# My blender is so laggy that its unusable, any suggestions

Tags: performance

So, two days ago I shut down my computer for a few hours. When I turned it back on and opened Blender, it was extremely slow and still is. (I've tested Unreal Engine and it runs smoothly). All the solutions I found involve Nvidia processors but I use Intel and I've had no luck finding issues.

```
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8130 
Laptop: LENOVO
OS: Windows 10
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try File->Load Factory settings, this will eliminate any preferences/add-ons that maybe causing the issue. Then uninstall/reinstall graphics drivers. Then review all running processes. Anti-virus/Windows update etc. Please post an answer when you find the fix or amend your question with more detail to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Might be a bit confusing.

So when I turned my computer back on it said my driver was not compatible, so I looked online. I got a file called "opengl32.dll" which let me open blender, thats when I found the lag.

I recently updated my graphic drivers and the lag was still happening, so I removed the "opengl32.dll".

So pretty much, I had to update my graphics driver and not add in that file. Thank you for the answers though :)

Comment: Adding that file is done for testing purposes only, Blender working with delay is normal in that case; once problem is found it should be deleted from Blender directory.

Answer (score 0):

It can be:

1. Driver issue, please update to the recent version.
2. Memory issue, you need to have at least 4G even for simple scenes.
3. Some Blender bug (yep, there are plenty of them!). If so please report to Blender developers.

Comment: Yup, it was my driver, I posted why it was still laggy below